# Loading external JS using requireJS in Magento2

Tags: magento2, requirejs

Following [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/167398) I try to add an **external JS** file named [Pym.js](http://blog.apps.npr.org/pym.js/) to my **Magento 2.3** shop.

I've tried several things but can not get it to work. My current setup it:

> app/design/frontend/*vendor*/*theme*/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  "paths": {
    "pym": "https://pym.nprapps.org/pym.v1"
  }
};
```

> app/design/frontend/*vendor*/*theme*/Magento_Theme/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="pym_child" template="Magento_Theme::js/pym_child.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/*vendor*/*theme*/Magento_Theme/templates/js/pym_child.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require([
    "pym"
  ], function () {

    var pymChild = new pym.Child();

  });
</script>
```

The error I keep getting is

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: pym is not defined
>       at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
>       at Module.check (require.js:866)
>       at Module. (require.js:1113)
>       at require.js:132
>       at require.js:1156
>       at each (require.js:57)
>       at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
>       at Module.check (require.js:917)
>       at Module.enable (require.js:1143)*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require([
    "https://pym.nprapps.org/pym.v1.js"
  ], function () {

    var pymChild = new pym.Child();

  });
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing .js at the end of your path in the config, if this works that could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For now I seem to have fixed the issue by changing the  quotes in requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
  paths: {
    'pym': 'https://pym.nprapps.org/pym.v1'
  }
};
```

and in pym_child.phtml I've edited the file to:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
     require(["jquery","pym"],function($,pym){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var pymChild = new pym.Child();
     })
 });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

If I keep having issues I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If third-party js is not working in your theme, you can try it by creating a custom module.

Please create a simple module and enable it.

Add the below content to in your module.

**File path**: `<vendor_name>/<module_name>/view/<your_scope>/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        pym: 'https://pym.nprapps.org/pym.v1'
    }
};
```

**Scope**: adminhtml, frontend, or base, where you want to use it.

You can use it in a script tag or js file like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require([
    "pym"
  ], function () {

    # Use it now 

  });
</script>
```

You need to run setup upgrade and deploy commands & test it.

This way, I used third-party js in my module or project.
It's working for me.